# Get Active Directory users in Group

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group, memberof

I'm trying to get all users in "Programmers" group from AD.

If I use directory entry as `LDAP://DC=Domain` and filter as `memberOf=CN=Programmers,CN=Users,DC=Domain`, I can get user list.

But if I directly use entry as `LDAP://CN=Programmers,CN=Users,DC=Domain`, I can't get any result.

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://CN=Programmers,CN=Users,DC=Domain")))
using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de))
{ 
    int pageIndex = PAGESIZE * nPage + 1;
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.Sort = new SortOption("samaccountname", SortDirection.Ascending);
    ds.VirtualListView = new DirectoryVirtualListView(0, PAGESIZE - 1, pageIndex);
    var results = ds.FindAll();
}
```

Can anybody tell why?

The reason why I want to use this instead of "memberOf" filter, is for the performance consideration. But I'm not sure if this will actually improve the performance. So the second question is: is there any performance difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked out...

The code should be:

```
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base;
ds.AttributeScopeQuery = "member";
```

Then it will work.